# How to differentiate between a Mobile phone IP address to a computer IP address?

Tags: ip, desktop, smartphone

I have a list of IP addresses, and I want to know how to filter mobile / smart phone IPs from the list...any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to get what you want... the best guess you may have is through the MAC Address. Just the IP won't give you any clue...

Comment: If this is in relation to a website, the `User-Agent:` header would be a better way to detect mobile phones.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Even if you had a list of IP addresses and corresponding MACs you can't.

Probably the only thing you can do is, if they are public IP addresses, and you have good knowledge of all the carriers networks, is take a best guess based on the known 3G/4G ranges of each ISP.

For example, if I see a 1.0.0.0/8 IP address (which [my phone often gets](https://serverfault.com/a/237523/7709)), chances are it's a smartphone on the Optus network.

But without that inside knowledge, you can't even begin to take a guess.

Comment: In addition to that, I can use tethering to have my computer use my phone's 3G connection or have my phone connect to the wifi, giving it the same IP address as my computer(s).

Comment: Nope. If you are anywhere else, you won't see the 10.0.0.0/8 network at all, it is a range for private use. If you know the _public_ addresses the mobile providers use to NAT their phones, you might get something. But e.g. my phone normally connects via WiFi, same as my notebook. And both are NATed by my ISP the same way. I also use my phone via tethering to use it as a "network card". And there are 3G dongles...

Comment: @von - if you look closely you will see I wrote 1.0.0.0 - not 10.0.0.0